# how to put tables on top of others on the right\left side of the page?

Tags: tables, minipage, multicolumn

this is my script. My aim is to get the first table on the left side, as it is, whereas on the right side of the page i'd like to construct 3 confusion matrix, one on the top of the others (as you can see in my pic where there are the yellow X)

[image]

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        Variable&Coefficient&Variance\\
        \midrule
        Intercept&-0.147&3.250640e-04\\
        InfoMovimenti&-0.003&5.651362e-07\\
        RichiediContanti&0.028&8.633829e-05\\
        anno professione&-0.002&3.325328e-07\\
        score QE&0.012&8.594122e-08\\
        Centro&-0.063&2.028436e-04\\
        Nord Est&-0.103&3.065296e-04\\
        Nord Ovest&-0.075&1.962815e-04\\
        insolvenze max&0.039&3.487840e-05\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\height}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
            & Regolari & Fragili \\
            \midrule
            0& 3247 & 721\\ 
            1& 253 & 779\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\height}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
            & Regolari & Fragili \\
            \midrule
            0& 9931 & 14\\ 
            1& 47 & 7\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The two instances of the instruction `\begin{minipage}{.3\height}` aren't right. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Generally, you can't rely on any output that your editor shows, if you also get an error message. For your laout, you could use two minipages. One for the table on the left and the second for the three tables on the right.

Comment: I'm not really practical in fact i've put this \begin{minipage}{.3\height} just because i wanted them one over the other, but i saw it didn't work; so i'm woundering how should I manipulate the heightness instead of the widthness

Comment: You can achieve this by putting all three tables in a single minipage. If you separate the tables by an empty line, the tables will automatically be placed one over another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would place a `tabular` -- not encased by a `minipage` -- on the left and a single `minipage` on the right; the `minipage` will contain the two smaller `tabular` environments. Incidentally, the argument of `minipage` specifies the width, not the height, of the environment.

I would also make an effort to make the tables more readable, mainly by aligning the numbers on the explicit or implicit decimal markers. This may be done by loading the `siunitx` package and using that package's `S` column type. The readability of the smaller tabulars would also be enhanced by providing more visible structure to their respective headers. Another way to improve the readability of the tabular material is to omit the `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=-1.3] C @{}}
        \toprule
        Variable & {Coefficient} & $Variance$\\
        \midrule
        Intercept        & -0.147 & 3.250640e{-}04\\
        InfoMovimenti    & -0.003 & 5.651362e{-}07\\
        RichiediContanti &  0.028 & 8.633829e{-}05\\
        anno professione & -0.002 & 3.325328e{-}07\\
        score QE         &  0.012 & 8.594122e{-}08\\
        Centro           & -0.063 & 2.028436e{-}04\\
        Nord Est         & -0.103 & 3.065296e{-}04\\
        Nord Ovest       & -0.075 & 1.962815e{-}04\\
        insolvenze max   &  0.039 & 3.487840e{-}05\\
        \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hfill % maximize the horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\raggedleft
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=3.0] @{}}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
            \cmidrule(l){2-3}
            & {Regolari} & {Fragili} \\
            \midrule
            0& 3247 & 721\\ 
            1&  253 & 779\\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=4.0] S[table-format=2.0] @{}}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
            \cmidrule(l){2-3}
            & {Regolari} & {Fragili} \\
            \midrule
            0& 9931 & 14\\ 
            1&   47 &  7\\
            \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        Variable&Coefficient&Variance\\
        \midrule
        Intercept&-0.147&3.250640e-04\\
        InfoMovimenti&-0.003&5.651362e-07\\
        RichiediContanti&0.028&8.633829e-05\\
        anno professione&-0.002&3.325328e-07\\
        score QE&0.012&8.594122e-08\\
        Centro&-0.063&2.028436e-04\\
        Nord Est&-0.103&3.065296e-04\\
        Nord Ovest&-0.075&1.962815e-04\\
        insolvenze max&0.039&3.487840e-05\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
            & Regolari & Fragili \\
            \midrule
            0& 3247 & 721\\
            1& 253 & 779\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}

\bigskip

        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
            & Regolari & Fragili \\
            \midrule
            0& 9931 & 14\\
            1& 47 & 7\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To create a bit more visual separation between the materials of the two `minipage` environments, it would be useful to insert a `\raggedleft` directive immediately after the start of the second `minipage`. Getting rid of the `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}` instructions would, incidentally, greatly improve the readability of the tabular materials.

Comment: Absolutely d'accord! I just took the users code snippets and made the two tabulars one above the other. I didn't take care of the layout. You did a much better job :-)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I've used this, there's no need of particular functions!

[image]

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Stime dal modello di regressione lineare}
\end{center}
    \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.5}
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        Variable&Coefficient&Pr(>|z|)\\
        \midrule
        Intercept&-0.147&5.09e-16 ***\\
        InfoMovimenti&-0.003&1.42e-05 ***\\
        RichiediContanti&0.028&0.00268 **\\
        anno professione&-0.002&0.00012 ***\\
        score QE&0.012&< 2e-16 ***\\
        Centro&-0.063&1.15e-05 ***\\
        Nord Est&-0.103&3.93e-09 ***\\
        Nord Ovest&-0.076&7.25e-08 ***\\
        insolvenze max&0.039&1.81e-11 ***\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Modello 2}
\label{mod2}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.4}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
            & Regolari & Fragili \\
            \midrule
            0& 336 & 14\\ 
            1& 3164 & 1486\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
                \caption{Train 0.5}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.4}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
            & Regolari & Fragili \\
            \midrule
            0& 9943 & 15\\ 
            1& 35 & 6\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \caption{test 0.7}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{0.4}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Reali} \\
        & Regolari & Fragili \\
        \midrule
        0& 9927 & 4\\ 
        1& 46 & 3\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{test 0.7}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: what is this? your answer? if it is, please extend it to complete small document and elaborate, in what it is better than accepted one.